# MATE and isolating alt-tab

Tags: workspaces, mate

I just changed over to MATE from GNOME in Ubuntu 20.04. One thing that's bothering me is workspace isolation. I want to be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only to the apps on the active workspace, not all the workspaces on which I've placed windows. GNOME has the setting available, but nothing seems to exist in MATE.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to update your habbits. Simply remember these new shorcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows from all workspaces forward
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows from all workspaces backward

---

If you do not want to remember new shortcuts - then redefine existing by:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows "'<Control><Alt>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-backward "'<Control><Alt><Shift>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all "'<Alt>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all-backward "'<Alt><Shift>Tab'"
```

to revert them to default use:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows "'<Alt>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-backward "'<Alt><Shift>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all "'<Control><Alt>Tab'"
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all-backward "'<Control><Alt><Shift>Tab'"
```

---

Also please note that *Windows List* applet on the bottom MATE Panel allows to switch between  two modes - "Show windows from current workspace" and "Show windows from all workspaces".

Comment: Switching between workspaces is what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: CTRL+ALT+TAB works for me, but those gsettings lines didn't change a thing :(

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but rather suggests that the problem is in asking the question.